# Exceptional Cases In wso2 Message Broker

Tags: wso2, message-queue, wso2-message-broker

I am using wso2 message broker as a message brokering system in my project. Before using wso2 message broker, I want to explore exceptional cases related to wso2 message broker queue/topic -

1. How many messages queue/topic can store if consumer is down and publisher is continuously sending message to queue/topic ?
2. What will happen if queue/topic is not available and publisher is trying to post message in queue/topic?
3. What is the maximum size of message queue/topic can store ? Is it configurable ?
4. What is the JSON message format of wso2 message broker?
5. Can consumer sends response to publisher after getting message from queue/topic ? If yes, How ?
6. What is the duration of queue/topic session timeout ? Is it configurable ?

Comment: Have you gone through the documentation to see whether you can find answers https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB310/WSO2+Message+Broker+Documentation

Answer (score 1):

Please find answers below.

> How many messages queue/topic can store if consumer is down and publisher is continuously sending message to queue/topic ?

This depends on how much space is allocated for MB server. The messages are persisted into the DB.

> What will happen if queue/topic is not available and publisher is
>   trying to post message in queue/topic?

Message Broker will not accept the messages. Will simply drop them.

> What is the maximum size of message queue/topic can store ? Is it
>   configurable ?

There is no defined limit. But MB is tested with upto 10MB messages. But the performance degrades drastically as the message size grows.

> What is the JSON message format of wso2 message broker?

There is no such thing.

> Can consumer sends response to publisher after getting message from
>   queue/topic ? If yes, How ?

This is not actually supported by AMQP. In AMQP the publisher and the subscriber is decoupled. SO through WSO2 MB you cannot get this done.

> What is the duration of queue/topic session timeout ? Is it
>   configurable ?

This can be set from the client side when connection is made.